# How can I sum the output of the two opamps and multiply the voltage swing to +2vcc and -vcc

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, constant-current, load, dual-supply

I have a VtoI circuit that you can see in the figure below. According to this circuit, I can receive a maximum sin current of 4 mA with a maximum load of 5 kΩ. Considering that the supply voltage for op-amps does not exceed positive and negative 22 V, I cannot place a higher load at the output of this circuit. This is because, with the constant sin current I want, the maximum sin voltage I can have is 4 mA * 5.5k = 22 V peak-to-peak.

Now, in order for the circuit to be able to support a higher resistance at the output (up to 10 kΩ) I have added an inverter to the output of this VtoI circuit to create a sine wave signal of the same amplitude but with a 180-degree phase shift compared to the original signal. And then, I have applied one of these voltage signals to each end of the load so that ultimately it can generate a sinusoidal voltage from +44 to -44 V. As a result, it keeps the current at a constant 4 mA.

[image]

You can see the result of the voltage signals of each end of the load in the below figure.

[image]

And also the sin current of the load in third figure,
[image]

Everything appeared to be fine during simulation. However, in practical implementation, when a 10 kΩ load is used, the op-amp outputs go into saturation. As a result, it is unable to generate a voltage signal with a rail-to-rail range of +44 to -44 V, causing the sinusoidal current to fall below 4 mA.

I've come to realize that it's essential to isolate the outputs of the two op-amps to prevent mutual interference. The question now is how to achieve this, and what is the best way to increase the load at the output of my op-amp while maintaining the sinusoidal current?

Comment: Apply a (power) buffer to the output.

Comment: doesn't that buffer need more voltage supply than +-22v?

Comment: Yes, it needs ± 22V.